# C# WPF Declare an ICommand in a single line

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I'm in the process of learning WPF and the MVVM design pattern. Currently the code in my ViewModel for a delete customer command looks like this:

```
    public class vmCustomers : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
...
        private ICommand _commandDeleteCustomer = null;
...
        public ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer
        {
            get
            {
                if (_commandDeleteCustomer == null)
                    _commandDeleteCustomer = new RelayCommand<object>(DeleteCustomerAction, DeleteCustomerPredicate);
                return _commandDeleteCustomer;
            }
        }

        private void DeleteCustomerAction(object o)
        {
            ...stuff...
        }

        private bool DeleteCustomerPredicate(object o)
        {
            ...stuff...
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I'd like to slim down the declaration of the ICommand to something like this so that I can reduce the coding overhead for each command:

```
public readonly ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer = new RelayCommand((obj) => DeleteCustomerAction(obj), (obj) => DeleteCustomerPredicate(obj));
```

But I get this error:

`A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property vmCustomers.DeleteCustomerAction(object)`

Is there a way I can declare the ICommand in a single line of code so that I can simply focus on business-related code rather than repeated infrastructure code.

Comment: Besides that the initialization expression will not compile, you should declare a readonly property `public ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer { get; }` instead of a field. Then move the initialization to the constructor: `CommandDeleteCustomer = new RelayCommand(...);`

Comment: Thanks @Clemens - I'd kind of got it down to that, except that I've declared CommandDeleteCustomer as a readonly class level variable, thus: ```public readonly ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer;```.

Comment: You would not be able to bind to a field (aka member variable). It has to be a public property.

Comment: @Clemens - You are right (have confirmed empirically). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your `RelayCommand.CanExecuteChanegd` hooks onto the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event you can drop the constructor initialization and initialize the property as read-only computed property in a single line statement:

```cs
// Creates a *new instance* on every Get() access
public ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer => new RelayCommand(...);

// The following is the verbose form of the previous single line property declaration:
public ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer
{
  get => new RelayCommand(...);
}
```

To ensure that the *same instance* is returned from the property, use

a) the null coalescing assignment operator (C# 8.0)

```cs
// Backing field required 
private ICommand commandDeleteCustomer;
public ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer => this.commandDeleteCustomer ??= new RelayCommand(...);

// The following is the verbose form of the previous property declaration
// and uses the null coalescing operator:
public ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer => this.commandDeleteCustomer = this.commandDeleteCustomer ?? new RelayCommand(...);
```

b) a property initializer (single line statement):

```cs
// Returns the *same instance* on every Get() access.
// Note that you can't reference instance members like fields and properties from the initializer. 
// This means the command delegates would have to be defined as 'private static'.
public ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer { get; } = new RelayCommand<object>(DeleteCustomerAction, DeleteCustomerPredicate);

private static void DeleteCustomerAction(object o)
{
  ...stuff...
}

private static bool DeleteCustomerPredicate(object o)
{
  ...stuff...
  return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you. This does literally answer my question about how to condense it down to a single line.

Comment: @MarkRoworth Be however aware that static methods will not allow to access data of a view model instance, e.g. "delete a customer" from a collection in the view model. In your question, you are not asking how to declare a command that uses static methods. Such a command would usually not make much sense.

Comment: @MarkRoworth I have added another solution to return the same instance (without the need of static members). Because it returns the same instance, we need a backing field as storage. It's a two liner but still a brief expression. However, the first version is preferable in most cases.

Comment: The "other solution" shows exactly what OP already has, just with a more modern syntax. Not sure if this really helps to avoid "*repeated infrastructure code*".

Comment: @Clemens I'm aware. But since he was asking for a brief declaration I thought to post this variant too (as it is shorter than what he got so far). We both know that property declaration syntax can't solve the problem of repeated code. Neither your nor my solution does provide a solution to this specific problem. The first part of your quoted sentence reads: *"Is there a way I can declare the ICommand in a single line of code [...]"*. Obviously only interested in a brief declaration syntax so I assume he misused some terms here. With repeated code he probably meant the explicit property body.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a read-only auto-implemented property

```
public ICommand CommandDeleteCustomer { get; }
```

and move the initialization statement to the view model constructor

```
public VmCustomers()
{
    CommandDeleteCustomer = new RelayCommand(...);
}
```